# Generate multiple jquery-UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have placed my jquery dialog content in a div. But whenever I'm initializing the dialog in this way:

```
$(".uof_add_form").dialog({
  autoOpen : false,
  height : 500,
  width : 600,
  modal : true,
  buttons : {
   "Done" : function() {
    $(this).close();
  }
  }
});
```

The content gets removed from my div. And for this reason I can not use

```
$("#new_form").on("click",".add_level", function(){
        var wrapper_data = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        wrapper_data.find(".uof_add_form").dialog("open");

});
```

to open my dialog.

As my contents are generated dynamically I need to use `$(this)`.

Is there any way with which my content will stay inside of my div?

I changed my code to initialize  on the click itself doing `display:none` on my div in this way:-

```
$("#new_form").on("click",".add_level", function(){
    var wrapper_data = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    wrapper_data.find(".add_level_pop").dialog({autoOpen : true, height : 500,width : 600,modal : true, buttons : {   "Done" : function() {  $(this).dialog('close'); } } });

});
```

The dialog opens on first click but on second click the dialog doesn't gets fired because **the content has been transferred to a different place on initialization of the dialog.**

I have also added a sample on **jsfiddle** please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinprasad/2Pv3q/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not sure that I understand your initial problem, from looking at the code in your fiddle, you might want to consider to:

- omit the class qualifier in your selector when you already have an `ID`, which will stick to the dialog element so you can always find your `<div>` in the `DOM` ([fiddle v3](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pv3q/3/))
- save the `<div>` to a variable on load, so you can access it without querying the DOM for it ([fiddle v4](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pv3q/4))

In both updated versions of your fiddle the dialog opens on second click, if that is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

---

As you try to solve a more generic situation, I have updated your example accordingly in [another fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/2Pv3q/7/). The dialog div is saved on the button using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function. To open the dialog, the saved dialog is used.

Comment: Sorry,Not exactly what I want, I can not do this  var $dialog = $( ".wrapper #dialog" );  as I don't know what will be my new generated ID and  in which wrapper div it belongs to.

Comment: But you should know at some point what `id` you have and be able to save a reference to the new element. A more dynamic example would help to understand the problem. Another thing (although you said that you can not use that part anyways): you should not use a chain of `.parent()` calls, try using jQuery's [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle code now, I have updated it. And please note that wrapper div is auto-generated.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs now.

Comment: Even if I replace all the IDs with class the issue remains the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/sachinprasad/2Pv3q/6/

Comment: Yeah I think this will works now. Thanks a lot for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of `.dialog()` as a handle :

```
var handle = $(".uof_add_form").dialog({
 [...]
});
```

then at some point,

```
handle.dialog("open");
```

Comment: I cannot use handle as my contents are generated dynamically

Comment: is it possible then to initialize the dialog at the point where you currently open it ? ie something like `wrapper_data.find('uof_add_form').dialog({ ... })` with `autoOpen: true` (and without the original declaration for `dialog`)?

Comment: Please check my updated question what happened when I did as you said.